# Node : how to set static port to udp client in node js

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp

I am very new to Udp Socket programming, here i implemented echo UDP Client which connects to UDP server

```
var buffer = require('buffer');
var udp = require('dgram');
// creating a client socket
var client = udp.createSocket('udp4');

//buffer msg
var data = Buffer.from('Pradip Shinde');

client.on('message',function(msg,info){
  console.log('Data received from server : ' + msg.toString());
  console.log('Received %d bytes from %s:%d\n',msg.length, info.address, info.port);
});

//sending msg
client.send(data,9300,'192.168.1.187',function(error){
  if(error){
    client.close();
  }else{
    console.log('Data sent from client!!!');
  }
});
```

when this client send msg to server, operating system assign the random port to this client but in my scenario i want static port which will never change, is it possible to assign static port to udp client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation, you can use `bind` method to do this,

> For UDP sockets, causes the dgram.Socket to listen for datagram messages on a named port and optional address that are passed as properties of an options object passed as the first argument. If port is not specified or is 0, the operating system will attempt to bind to a random port. If address is not specified, the operating system will attempt to listen on all addresses. Once binding is complete, a 'listening' event is emitted and the optional callback function is called.

Try using

```
// Creating a client socket
var client = udp.createSocket('udp4');

// Bind your port here
client.bind({
  address: 'localhost',
  port: 8000,
  exclusive: true
});
```

For more information follow this [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_socket_bind_port_address_callback).

Comment: but i guess binding is for server , also i tried your solution on client code it throws me error Error [ERR_SOCKET_ALREADY_BOUND]: Socket is already bound

Comment: Yeah it could be for server, where did you bind your socket

Comment: Try binding it just after `var client = udp.createSocket('udp4');`

Comment: yeah it works when i shifted position after creation but how does that matter?

Comment: When you do `client.send`, It needs a port for send data right, So in that line the connection should be established. That's why you got the above error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180398/discussion-between-janith-kasun-and-pradip-shinde).

Comment: Set `exclusive: false` to to avoid rebind errors to the same port.